# Не устанавливается WXWIDGETS для CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks

Не знаю пытаюсь установить уже раз 10-й наверно, и все одна и та же ошибка

Устанавливаю по этой инструкции http://habrahabr.ru/post/212027/

Вот ошибка при вводе 3-й строки 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Очень хочу поставить а решить эту проблему не в состоянии

Comment: Погуглите *wxwidgets regcustom.h stdio.h no such file or directory*, кое-что находится. Например, [здесь](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?p=158860#p158860) (сам не проверял, ибо предпочитаю не жрать кактусы сутками, а портатить несколько секунд на `sudo apt-get install libwxbase3.0-dev libwxgtk3.0-dev`)

Comment: ваша ссылка на кодлайт, а у меня codebloks

Comment: Так установка wxwidgets с конкретной IDE мало связана, во всяком случае на этом этапе. А вообще насколько принципиально использовать именно mingw? В C::B ведь можно указать любой компилятор. Когда развлекался с wx под Windows, помнится, вообще ваткомом собирал, просто подключая в проект их *.lib.

Comment: Мне нужно писать визуальные приложения, но я не могу из за того что WXWIDGETS не хочет устанавливаться, как вы можете видеть на картинке установка ловит баттхерт и все, но на самом деле когда скачиваешь кодблокс с офф сайта там есть версия с компилятором, но мне ни то ни другое не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужно просто решить задачу установки библиотеки wxWidgets, не разбираясь в особенностях её сборки, то можете воспользоваться пакетом [msys2](http://msys2.github.io/), который предоставит искомое.

Для начала установите msys2, как это подробно показано на скриншотах по приведённой ссылке, а затем, открыв терминал msys2 из меню виндовса, введите команду:

```
pacman -Ss wxwidgets
```

Она выведет список доступных пакетов этого фреймворка. В моём случае получилось такое:

```
$ pacman -Ss wxwidgets
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-wxPython 3.0.2.0-1 (mingw-w64-i686)
    A wxWidgets GUI toolkit for Python (mingw-w64)
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-wxWidgets 3.0.2-5 (mingw-w64-i686)
    A C++ library that lets developers create applications for Windows, Linux
    and UNIX (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-wxPython 3.0.2.0-1 (mingw-w64-x86_64)
    A wxWidgets GUI toolkit for Python (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-wxWidgets 3.0.2-5 (mingw-w64-x86_64)
    A C++ library that lets developers create applications for Windows, Linux
    and UNIX (mingw-w64)
```

Выбираем нужный пакет и устанавливаем. Менеджер пакетов разрешит все зависимости автоматически. В общем, получается всё просто как в линуксах.

```
$ pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-wxWidgets
разрешение зависимостей...
проверка конфликтов...

Пакеты (7) mingw-w64-i686-cppunit-1.13.2-3  mingw-w64-i686-jbigkit-2.1-1
           mingw-w64-i686-libjpeg-turbo-1.4.0-2  mingw-w64-i686-libpng-1.6.16-1
           mingw-w64-i686-libtiff-4.0.3-4  mingw-w64-i686-xz-5.2.1-1
           mingw-w64-i686-wxWidgets-3.0.2-5

Будет загружено:   9,58 MiB
Будет установлено:  62,19 MiB

:: Приступить к установке? [Y/n]
```

Comment: что такое msys? и что я получу в итоге? мне нужно чтобы в итоге codeblocks видел эти виджеты

Comment: Из wiki: "В дополнение, компонент MinGW, известный как MSYS (Minimal SYStem) предоставляет win32-порты окружения легковесной Unix-подобной оболочки, включающей rxvt и набор инструментов POSIX, достаточный для запуска скриптов autoconf". А говоря проще, получаете готовую для сборки проектов среду посредством mingw. MSys2 - тоже самое, только проще в установке и в плане управления пакетами. На выходе получите собранный из исходников wxWidgets. Далее, вероятно, уже сможете его подключить к своей IDE.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lgl700jcmjnooqw/IMG_23112015_000000.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Судя по ошибкам компиляции проблема в том, что компилятор не находит стандартные заголовочные файлы, находящиеся в папке include.

1) Нужно убедиться, что путь до каталога установки MinGW не содержит пробелов и русских символов.

2) Задать переменные окружения CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH и LIBRARY_PATH. К примеру если каталог установки C:\mingw, то CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH должна содержать значение C:\mingw\include, а LIBRARY_PATH значение C:\mingw\lib.

3) Перезагрузить компьютер после установки переменных окружения.

Подробнее смотреть [тут](http://embeddedprogrammer.blogspot.ru/2012/10/windows-environment-variables-for-mingw.html)

Comment: не помогло! задавал переменные, даже ставил компилятор отдельно от codeblocks, не пашет пишет ту же ошибку! Компьютер перезагружал

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с аналогичной ошибкой в `Windows7-x64`. Решилось всё использованием оболочки в комплекте с `TDM-GCC-32 5.1.0-3`. Странно, но факт, стандартный `cmd` тупит и теряет пути. Сборку делал со следующими командами:

```
cd %WXWIN%\build\msw

mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc USE_XRC=1 SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 BUILD=debug UNICODE=1 USE_OPENGL=1 VENDOR=cb CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++11 -fno-keep-inline-dllexport" >log.txt 2>&1

mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc USE_XRC=1 SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 BUILD=release UNICODE=1 USE_OPENGL=1 VENDOR=cb CXXFLAGS="-std=gnu++11 -fno-keep-inline-dllexport" >log2.txt 2>&1
```

`wxWidgets-3.0.3` собрался отлично и со всеми библиотеками, необходимыми для запуска. Все остальные действия по установке аналогичны, тем, что приводятся в большинстве инструкций по установке.

**P.S.** Старайтесь избегать длинных путей, пробелов и кириллицы при установке. Как видно из параметров стены текста в ходе сборки выводятся не в консоль, а в лог-файл.